# How can I partition a vector?

Tags: r, vector

How can I build a function

```
slice(x, n)
```

which would return a list of vectors where each vector except maybe the last has size n, i.e.

```
slice(letters, 10)
```

would return

```
list(c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j"),
     c("k", "l", "m", "n", "o", "p", "q", "r", "s", "t"),
     c("u", "v", "w", "x", "y", "z"))
```

?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
slice<-function(x,n) {
    N<-length(x);
    lapply(seq(1,N,n),function(i) x[i:min(i+n-1,N)])
}
```

Answer (score 8):

You can use the `split` function:

```
split(letters, as.integer((seq_along(letters) - 1) / 10))
```

If you want to make this into a new function:

```
slice <- function(x, n) split(x, as.integer((seq_along(x) - 1) / n))
slice(letters, 10)
```